# How to allow certain html tags?

Tags: php, html, xss

I got a textarea where the user can write an article. The article can contain text (bold and italic), links and youtube videos. How do I allow those certain html tags and still post secure xss-preventing code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [**HTMLPurifier**](http://htmlpurifier.org/), to ensure that you only keep HTML

- That is valid
- and only contains tags and attributes you've choosen to allow

I should add that PHP provides the [`strip_tags()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function, but it's not that good *(quoting)* :

> Because `strip_tags()` does not actually validate the HTML, partial or
>   broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.
>   
>  
> This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that
>   you allow using `allowable_tags`, including the style and onmouseover
>   attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that
>   will be shown to other users.

Comment: Thx! Seems like htmlpurifier is the way to go. Just to clarify; htmlpurifier prevents xss, sql injections and all other dangerous code?

Comment: I've used it a couple of times, to clean user-input and make sure it only contains tags I had choosen to allow; if you choose the allowed tags/attributes carefully, it'll prevent XSS. But it will not do anything about SQL Injections: those are another problem, that you'll solve by making sure what you put into SQL queries is safe *(integers should be integers, strings should be properly escaped, ... or you should use prepared statements)*

Comment: Is mysql_real_escape_string enough to cover SQL injections?

Comment: For strings, it should be ; for other kind of fields, you should ensure they contain what you expect *(for integers, you could use `intval()`, for example)*

Comment: Okey so I ended up doing this:

1. User post article
2. Processing text with HTMLpurifier and mysql_real_escape_string()
3. Inserting into database
4. Reading from the database with nl2br()

Works perfectly!

Comment: Is this still the go-to tech for this scenario, or is there a newer technology that is being adapted that you're aware of?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for real XSS protection I suggest to use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Doing it yourself is pretty hard if not impossible to do. And is bound to have mistakes ( / holes) in it.