# php htmlentities tags exceptions leave working only certains

Tags: php, html-entities, strip-tags

I have no problem to disallow all HTML tags with this code that works fine:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo "<span class='names'>".htmlentities($row['username'])."</span>:<span class='messages'>".htmlentities($row['msg'])."</span><br>";  
}
```

But what if I want to allow some tags exceptions?

The result that I want is to disable any tag except `<p><b><h2>`

Example: (allowing `<b>` and disallowing `<div>`)

```
<b>sometext</b><div>sometext</div>
```

Expected Result:

**sometext** `<div>sometext</div>`

See the image:[image]

Comment: what happens when you run strip_tags before the htmlentities / specialchars_decode calls?

Comment: the strip_tags just does not make any effect.. I have not yet figured out how to use it properly..

Comment: please add some example output for each step. If you use strip_tags as the first step, it should work as advertised.

Comment: Try $text = htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", true);  First.  This will ensure you only encode your html once

Comment: I am not sure how to include strip_tags.. I am new to this.. please can you post some example please?

Comment: Start doing basic debugging: output your $text before/after each stage so you can see what's happening.

Comment: here's the example what I'm trying: http://codepad.org/5Tb52Rro

Comment: How is that code not doing what you wanted?  You wanted to allow the <b> tags and they remain in the string, and the <h1> tag got stripped out.

Comment: In the example link I want to have a real bold element (allowed tag), and a disallowed tag <div>sometext</div> exactly as is... But doesn't work

Comment: Based on your new information, you don't really need a tag stripper, you need a view interpreter that only allows certain tags to work and letting the other tags appear as plaintext and not as html instructions for display. Does that sum it up?

Comment: @islanddave Do you know how to do it? Please it's driving me crazy..

Comment: Never used it personally, but try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250566/how-to-allow-certain-html-tags

Comment: I don't know if htmlpurifier will let the tags pass through as unexecuted text. Why do you have that requirement? Why not just filter out all disallowed tags?

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job, parsing the HTML code using `DOMDocument`. It seemed somehow more reliable than regular expressions (what happens if the user inserts an attribute in a forbidden tag? maybe containing `<>`?), especially after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags); it requires more work though, and is not necessarily faster.

```
<?

$allowed = ['strong'];  // your allowed tags
$text = "<div>\n" .
        "    <div style=\"color: #F00;\">\n" .
        "       Your <strong>User Text</strong> with DIVs.\n".
        "   </div>\n" .
        "   more <strong>text</strong>\n" .
        "</div>\n";

echo selective_escape($text, $allowed);
/* outputs:

&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;div style="color: #F00;"&gt;
       Your <strong>User Text</strong> with DIVs.
   &lt;/div&gt;
   more <strong>text</strong>
&lt;/div&gt;

*/





/** Escapes HTML entities everywhere but in the allowed tags.
 */
function selective_escape($text, $allowed_tags) {

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    /* DOMDocument normalizes the document structure when loading,
       adding a bunch of <p> around text where needed. We don't need
       this as we're working only on small pieces of HTML.
       So we pretend this is a piece of XML code.
       */
    // $doc->loadHTML($text);
    $doc->loadXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body>" . $text . "</body>\n");

    // find the body
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);

    // do stuff
    $child = $body->firstChild;
    while ($child != NULL) {
        $child = selective_escape_node($child, $allowed_tags);
    }

    // output the innerHTML. need to loop again
    $retval = "";

    $child = $body->firstChild;
    while ($child != NULL) {
        $retval .= $doc->saveHTML($child);
        $child = $child->nextSibling;
    }

    return $retval;
}






/** Escapes HTML for tags that are not in $allowed_tags for a DOM tree.
 *  @returns the next sibling to process, or NULL if we reached the last child.
 *
 *  The function replaced a forbidden tag with two text nodes wrapping the
 *  children of the old node.
 */
function selective_escape_node($node, $allowed_tags) {

    // preprocess children
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $child = $node->firstChild;
        while ($child != NULL) {

            $child = selective_escape_node($child, $allowed_tags);

        }
    }

    // check if there is anything to do on $node as well
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        if (!in_array($node->nodeName, $allowed_tags)) {

            // move children right before $node
            $firstChild = NULL;
            while ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
                $child = $node->firstChild;

                if ($firstChild == NULL) $firstChild = $child;
                $node->removeChild($child);

                $node->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $node);
            }

            // now $node has no children.
            $outer_html = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);

            // two cases. either ends in "/>", or in "</TAGNAME>".
            if (substr($outer_html, -2) === "/>") {

                // strip off "/>"
                $outer_html = substr($outer_html, 0, strlen($outer_html) - 2);

            } else {

                // find the closing tag
                $close_tag = strpos($outer_html, "></" . $node->nodeName . ">");

                if ($close_tag === false) {

                    // uh-oh. something wrong
                    return NULL;

                } else {

                    // strip "></TAGNAME>"
                    $outer_html = substr($outer_html, 0, $close_tag);

                }

            }

            // put a textnode before the first child
            $txt1 = $node->ownerDocument->createTextNode($outer_html . ">");
            // and another before $node
            $txt2 = $node->ownerDocument->createTextNode("</" . $node->nodeName . ">");

            // note that createTextNode automatically escapes "<>".
            $node->parentNode->insertBefore($txt1, $firstChild);
            $node->parentNode->insertBefore($txt2, $node);

            // pick the next node to process
            $next = $node->nextSibling;
            // remove node
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

            return $next;
        }
    }

    // go to next sibling
    return $node->nextSibling;

}

?>
```

Comment: I pasted your code exactly as is, but I have this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /path.php on line 3"

Comment: @user3746998 You are using PHP < 5.4.0, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271874/shorthand-for-arrays-is-there-a-literal-syntax-like-or). Replace `["strong"]` with `array("strong")`. Careful anyway, if you are using a very old version of PHP, you might not have all the DOM classes used in the code.

Comment: I've included your code in a .php file using require_once and all works fine. But if I use this combination Please look at [This Example](http://s30.postimg.org/xccs59k6p/code.png), in the output everything is included inside <p></p>... wtf ?! Please look at the [Result Image](http://s30.postimg.org/w6rm8t6cx/result.png). What I'm wrong please help!

Comment: @user3746998 The problem is that `DOMDocument` is aware of the rules of HTML: in HTML 4.01 Strict for example no text is allowed in `<body>`. So it wraps your text around `</p>` to conform to the schema. Maybe with a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration it is possible to allow text in the body, but PHP will potentially apply other normalization rules to the document. So I updated the code to load HTML as XML and work around any normalization.

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS YOUR RESULT:**

Please be aware at bottom to set which tags would be allowed:

```
function strip_html_tags( $text )
{
    $text = preg_replace(
        array(
          // Remove invisible content
            '@<b[^>]*?>.*?</b>@siu',   // HERE IS YOUR DISSALOW TAG WITH CONTENT
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
          // Add line breaks before and after blocks
            '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
            '@</?((h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
            '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
            '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
            '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
            '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
            '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        ),
        array(
            "\$0", // RETURNED STATEMENT
             ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
            "\$0", "\$0", "\$0", "\$0", "\$0", "\$0",
            "\$0", "\$0",
        ),
        $text );
    $to_strip =  strip_tags( $text, '<b>' );            // STRIP YOUR BOLD TAGS
    // add here to another + add content on above '@<b[^>]*?>.*?</b>@siu', and returns "\$0" on arrays
    return $to_strip;
}

      $e = '<b>from_bold_text</b><div>from_div_text</div>';

      echo strip_html_tags($e);
```

**RESULT:**

```
   from_bold_text<div>from_div_text</div>
```

---

```
shell:~$ php ar.php 
<b>sometext</b>sometext

shell:~$ cat ar.php 
<?php

$t ="<b>sometext</b><div>sometext</div>";

$text = htmlentities($t, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
$text = strip_tags($text, "<p><b><h2>");

echo $text;

shell:~$ php ar.php 
<b>sometext</b>sometext
```

Note: strip_tags will NOT remove a values inside it, only tags will be removed.

$text = '**sometext**sometext';
$text2 = strip_tags($text, '**');
var_dump($text2); // it will show allowed tags**  and values.

For removing a values inside it use regex or another function with CONTENT ON MANUAL:

```
<?php
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}
?>

Sample text:
$text = '<b>sample</b> text with <div>tags</div>';

Result for strip_tags($text):
sample text with tags

Result for strip_tags_content($text):
text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '<b>'):
<b>sample</b> text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '<b>', TRUE);
text with <div>tags</div>
```

---

Your expectation:

```
$text = '<b>sometext_from_bold</b><div>sometext_from_div</div>';
```

// here goes function function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {
.... }

// Your results

```
echo strip_tags_content($text, '<b>', FALSE);
```

RESULT:

```
<b>sometext_from_bold</b>
```

Comment: I need to this to disallow any html tag from a chat and allow just the bold tag... You understand what I mean? Your code is nice, but I don't need to remove tags like <div></div> etc, if the user writes <div></div>, this will appear in the chat exactly as it is! No need to remove tags, just show raw like code!

Comment: see the image, can you post an update working example please? It would be great. Thank in advance

Comment: Hey, your result is done, you need be aware when you want to filter string put it to above inside regex and save the content then returns. After that strip tags any what you want. Be aware `\$0` to put as returned value from filtered strings so I've added from the start of array() in second method of `preg_replace()` function. Here goes returned statements.